# Display Wordpress Post Thumnails with Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Dear StackOverflow I'm having some problems with displaying wordpress post thumbnails as per the image below. I've create a one page template that has queries for each post type I want to show but one of them I'd like to have horizontally with a show more/less buttons depending on how many are remaining.  I presume I need to put these in to seperate divs then Jquery to scroll the divs but I'm quite lost.  The image below should explain it a little better.

[image: Suggested Layout]
Obviously the sections to the right would be hidden until required to scroll in and replace current images.

I'm open to all suggestions of showing/replacing the view but a set number of items only at a time... at the moment, 7.

Below is the relevant section code so far which isn't correct but its as close as I can get it just now.

```
    <section id="releases" class="content" >
  <?php 
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'releases',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
  );
  $query = new WP_Query($args);

  //
  $first = 7;
  $next = 6;
  ?>

  <?php if($query->have_posts()): ?>
    <div class="slide">
    <?php while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
      <div class="release col-3 left">
      <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
      </div>
      <?php $current_position = $query->current_post + 1; ?>
      <?php if ($current_position < $query->found_posts && $current_position % $first == 0) : ?>
    <!-- -->
      <div class="release col-3 left">
        SHOWMORE</div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      </div><div class="slide">

      <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
</section>
```

Thank you for any help you may give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html is the main part here. I wont be able to write the code as there are many conditions you will have to check. But if you need a psedu code here is what you have to do.

1. Fetch and count all the posts.
2. if count is less then 7, then only generate one div. No need of scrolling. But if its more than 7 and less than 13 then generate 2 divs and so on.
3. So the html should be something like this.

   ```
   <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="slide">
          <ul>
             <li>Post 1</li>
             <li>Post 2</li>
             <li>Post 3</li>
             <li>Post 4</li>
             <li>Post 5</li>
             <li>Post 6</li>
             <li>Post 7</li>
             <li class="next">Next</li>
          </ul>
       </div>
       <div class="slide hidden">
          <ul>
             <li>Post 8</li>
             <li>Post 9</li>
             <li>Post 10</li>
             <li>Post 11</li>
             <li>Post 12</li>
             <li>Post 13</li>
             <li class="next">Next</li>
          </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

   .slide{display:inline;width:960px;}
   .slide ul li{display:inline;list-style-type:none;}
   .hidden{display:none;}
4. Now in jquery all you have to do is

   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $('.slide').click(function(){
         $(this).hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
         $(this).next().show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
      });
   });

Comment: The use of this post as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089101/add-class-to-every-4-posts-and-8-posts-wordpress-loop I now have very close to what I need. Thank you Omer

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this to enough of a degree to share with others... you can change the slide action to suit your requirements but at least you dont have to search the internet for what you need.

The Wordpress code for the post thumbnails is:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // Show the next slide after clicking the "next" button/link.
  $('.next').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().hide("slow");
    $(this).parent().parent().next('.slide').show("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.col-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
#slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.slide {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 960px;
}
.slide ul li {
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <section id="releases" class="content" >
    <?php 
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'releases',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    echo '<div id="slider">';
    for($i=1; $query->have_posts(); $i++)
    {
      $query->the_post();
      $prePost='';
      $postPost='';

      if($i==1)
      {
        $prePost='<div class="slide"><ul>';
      }
      if($i==7)
      {
        $postPost='<li class="release col-3 left next">SEE MORE</li></ul></div>';
        // $i=0;
      }
      if($i==8)
      {
        $prePost='<div class="slide hidden"><ul>';
      }
      if($i==14)
      {
        $postPost='<li class="release col-3 left next">SEE MORE</li></ul></div>';
        $i=7;
      }

      echo $prePost, '<li class="release col-3 left"><div class="inner">';
      the_post_thumbnail();
      echo '</div></li>', $postPost;
    }
    echo '</div>';
    ?>
  </section>
```

This is taken from my live environment but at 6am I might have got things a little wrong.

I'm happy to help anyone who has issues with this to make it work, I know how much of a ball ache it can be.